# Python 3 - Tkinter - Button not holding function with args

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Following Problem, im generating Buttons from a list with `globals()`. For each button there should be a function behind it that runs with the 'at that time' given args. For that im using `lambda` to give args to the function...

How the Buttons are created:

```
counter = 0
if len(match_id_list) >= 14:
    for i in range(1, 4):
        for j in range(1, 6):
            match_map, \
            match_timestamp, \
            match_gamemode, \
            match_duration, \
            match_player_kills, \
            match_telemetry_id, \
            match_telemetry_url = Player.match_search(match_id_list[counter], player_id)

            globals()[counter] = Button(player_matches_frame, text=f'{match_map} | {match_gamemode} | {match_player_kills} Kill/s',
                                        width=100, height=3)
            globals()[counter].grid(column=i, row=j, padx=10, pady=10)
            counter += 1
```

When i add a command with specific args to each Button it looks like this:

```
globals()[counter] = Button(player_matches_frame, text=f'{match_map} | {match_gamemode} | {match_player_kills} Kill/s',
                                        width=100, height=3, command=lambda: match_analysis(match_telemetry_id, match_telemetry_url))
```

It should use the variables that were created for that instance, but what it takes is the Last given ones. Im not sure if thats because the `command` arg or the `lambda`. Anyway, is there maybe a fix or a better way to solve it?

***Code for Testing / Reproducing:***

```
from tkinter import *

id_list = ["000", "001", "002", "003", "004"]
url = ["000.com", "001.com", "002.com", "003.com", "004.com"]

def match_analysis(url):
    print(url)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

for i in range(len(id_list)):
    globals()[i] = Button(root, text=id_list[i], command=lambda: match_analysis(url[i]))
    globals()[i].grid(column=0, row=i, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: (1) Using "globals()" in this way is bad style, create an own list or dict to store the buttons. (2) Replace the lambda by something like `lambda tid=match_telemetry_id, turl=match_telemetry_url: match_analysis(tid, turl)`. Storing the values in parameter defaults is the usual approach.

Comment: Jep, it works with the lambda parameters, i will also try to create buttons with a list later on. Thanks for the fast Help!